# Using Distance Matrix for Multi class classification for SVM

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, multi-class

I am working on bag of words technique for image recognition project and after I run k means I get a distance matrix and I have no idea how to apply that to svm to recognize images ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common Kernerl SVM requires a (valid) Gram matrix. You can turn your distance matrix to a Kernel matrix and feed it into the SVM to see what it spits.

In general, Kernel matrix are *"diagonal heavy"*-ey (I'm pretty sure I read that term in this very site actually), in the sense that they do not measure distance, but a sense of similarity (so big distance should imply a small value in the Kernel matrix, while small distances convey large values in the Kernel matrix).

---

This question provides some references which might guide you in the endeavor: [Turn a distance measure into a kernel function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146309/turn-a-distance-measure-into-a-kernel-function)