# How I can convert distance (Euclidean) to similarity score

Tags: clustering, k-means, distance, euclidean

I am using $k$ means clustering to cluster speaker voices. When I compare an utterance with clustered speaker data I get (Euclidean distance-based) average distortion. This distance can be in range of $[0,\infty]$. I want to convert this distance to a $[0,1]$ similarity score. Please guide me on how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 29):

If $d(p_1,p_2)$ represents the euclidean distance from point $p_1$ to point $p_2$,

$$\frac{1}{1 + d(p_1, p_2)}$$

is commonly used.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, if we have $X = (x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_t)$ and $Y = (Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,...,Y_n)$ where each $ x $ and $ y $  is of dimension $ D $. Then we can define similarity such as,  $$Similarity = \frac{1}{t} \sum\limits_{i=1}^t \frac{1}{ 1+ minDistance(x_i, Y)}$$.

Comment: I understand that the plus 1 in the denominator is to avoid divide by zero error. But I have found that the plus one value disproportionately affects d(p1,p2) values that are greater than 1 and ultimately reduces similarity score significantly. Is there another way to do this? Maybe s = 1-d(p1,p2)

Answer (score 15):

You could also use: $\frac{1}{e^{dist}}$ where `dist` is your desired distance function.

Comment: Can you please give any reference book/documentation related to this equation in which you found it? @Dougal

Comment: @AnimeshKumarPaul I didn't write this answer, just improved its formatting.  But it's frequently used as a version of e.g. a "generalized RBF kernel"; see e.g. [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/64126/9964). That question concerns whether the output is a positive definite kernel; if you don't care about that, though, it at least satisfies an intuitive notion of similarity that more distant points are less similar.

Comment: @Justlife : Google for this one "encyclopedia of distances" and pick the result with the pdf document.

Comment: Which is similar to: $sim = e^{-dist}$

Answer (score 13):

It sounds like you want something akin to cosine similarity, which is itself a similarity score in the unit interval. In fact, a direct relationship between Euclidean distance and cosine similarity exists!

Observe that
$$
||x-x^\prime||^2=(x-x^\prime)^T(x-x^\prime)=||x||+||x^\prime||-2||x-x^\prime||.
$$

While cosine similarity is 
$$
f(x,x^\prime)=\frac{x^T x^\prime}{||x||||x^\prime||}=\cos(\theta)
$$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $x$ and $x^\prime$.

When $||x||=||x^\prime||=1,$ we have 
$$
||x-x^\prime||^2=2(1-f(x,x^\prime))
$$
and
$$
f(x,x^\prime)=x^T x^\prime,
$$

so

$$
1-\frac{||x-x^\prime||^2}{2}=f(x,x^\prime)=\cos(\theta)
$$ in this special case.

From a computational perspective, it may be more efficient to just compute the cosine, rather than Euclidean distance and then perform the transformation.

Answer (score 10):

How about a [Gaussian kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel) ?

$K(x, x') = \exp\left( -\frac{\| x - x' \|^2}{2\sigma^2} \right)$

The distance $\|x - x'\|$ is used in the exponent. The kernel value is in the range $[0, 1]$. There is one tuning parameter $\sigma$. Basically if $\sigma$ is high, $K(x, x')$ will be close to 1 for any $x, x'$. If $\sigma$ is low, a slight distance from $x$ to $x'$ will lead to $K(x,x')$ being close to 0.

Comment: Note that this answer and [@Unhandled exception's](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/158303/9964) are very related: this is $\exp\left( - \gamma d(x, x')^2 \right)$, where that one [introducing a scaling factor] is $\exp\left( - \gamma d(x, x') \right)$, a Gaussian kernel with $\sqrt{d}$ as the metric. This will [still be a valid kernel](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/148031/9964), though the OP doesn't necessarily care about that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a distance metric that is naturally between 0 and 1, like Hellinger distance. Then you can use 1 - distance to obtain similarity.

Answer (score 0):

All answers given so far are correct in the sense that they will convert a distance $d \in [0, \infty]$ to a similarity $ s \in [0, 1]$, such that:

- $(d \rightarrow 0) \Rightarrow (s \rightarrow 1)$
- $(d \rightarrow \infty) \Rightarrow (s \rightarrow 0)$

However, a point that is not often addressed is the scale of $d$. When working with similarity, we commonly want to use a threshold — say of $0.5$ — to decide whether two vectors are "similar enough". But unless vector distances are relatively short, most reciprocal-based conversion methods will rapidly approach zero, making it hard to find an adequate threshold.

For example, imagine a domain where $d < 100$ for "similar" vectors. Using the common reciprocal conversion:

$$s = \frac{1}{1 + d}$$

The similarity between two vectors such that $d = 49$ will be $0.02$ — a rather counter-intuitive value for "close" similarity.

An alternative in this case is to use a conversion method that takes into account the expected distance range. For example, given an empirical upper distance limit $d_{max}$, we can calculate $s$ as:

$$s = 1 - min \left ( \frac{d}{d_{max}} , 1 \right )$$

In the above case, setting $d_{max} = 200$ would lead to $s = 0.755$, which is a much more intuitive result for two "similar" vectors.

The question remains of how to choose $d_{max}$. In the common scenario where we want to identify a vector's class by comparing it with an exemplar set, a simple procedure would be:

1. Calculate the average vector for the exemplar set;
2. Find the maximum distance $d^*$ between the average and the exemplar vectors;
3. Decide on a suitable similarity $s^*$ for $d^*$;
4. Calculate $d_{max}$ such that:

$$d_{max} = \frac{d^*}{(1 - s^*)}$$

If we set $s^* = 0.9$, that would make $d_{max}$ equal to ten times the maximum distance between the exemplar set average and its entries.